# Recursive array type typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have the type
`type Atom = string | boolean | number`. I want to define a type of array like:

`NestedArray = Atom | [a_0, a_1, ... , a_n]` where each `a_i` is an `Atom`, or a `NestedArray`.

Can this be achieved in Typescript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Type aliases can't reference themselves, so this naïve approach will fail:

```
type NestedArray = Atom | Array<NestedArray | Atom> //Type alias 'NestedArray' circularly references itself.
```

Interfaces can however reference themselves:

```
interface NestedArray extends Array<NestedArray | Atom> {

}
```

And we can define an extra union at the top level to handle the root case:

```
type Atom = string | boolean | number

interface NestedArray extends Array<NestedArray | Atom> {

}

type AtomOrArray = Atom | NestedArray;

//Usage
let foo: AtomOrArray = [
    "",
    1, 
    [1, 2, ""]
]   

let bar: AtomOrArray =  ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Now typescript allow type circularly references itself, such like this:

```js
type RArray = (string | RArray)[];
```

And if you want to define a generic type in recursive function, can use `interface ...<T> extends (T|...<T>)[]`

```js
interface RA<T> extends Array<T | RA<T>> { }
```

For example, create a function to get sum recursivily

```js
function sum(arr: RA<number>) {
  let res = 0;
  arr.forEach((n) => {
    if (Array.isArray(n)) {
      res += sum(n);
    } else {
      res += n;
    }
  });
  return res;
}
console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, [4, [5]], [[6]]]))
// output: 21
```

But this way has some disadvantage, compiler can't know the specific type of `n`

```js
arr.forEach((n) => {
    if (Array.isArray(n)) { // typeof n: `number | RA<number>`
      res += sum(n);
    } else {
      res += n;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](http://%20this%20answer)

Since typescript 3.7 you can create a general recoursive type:

```
type Tree<T> = T | Array<Tree<T>>
```

And then use it like this:

```
let stuff: Tree<string | boolean | number> = ["lala", [1, "stuffy"], 3, false];
```