# Typescript 2D variadic template

Tags: typescript, templates, generics, variadic

I currently have an interface using a data member of an array of some other interface type, which can be determined by an enum:

```js
enum E { a, b, c }
interface E2Data {
    [E.a]: { a: string },
    [E.b]: { b: string },
    [E.c]: { c: string }
}

interface A<T extends E[] = E[]> {
    data: { [i in keyof T]: T[i] extends E ? E2Data[T[i]] : never }
}

// Can give the enums in the template, and get autocomplete in the data.
let a1: A<[E.a, E.b]> = {
    data: [{ a: "" }, { b: "" }]
};

// Or can get autocomplete with type assertion on elements.
// Ideally this would infer template types too, but apparently not.
let a2: A = {
    data: [ <E2Data[E.a]>{ a: "" }, <E2Data[E.b]>{ b: "" } ]
}
```

According to my understanding, I can now use `a1.data` and `a2.data` as arrays, but `a1.data` knows the type of each element (so actually a tuple?)

**Now** I want to use a 2D array for `interface A`'s data.

I thought the below would work, but it would not allow me to index `E2Data` using `T[i][j]`.

```js
interface B<T extends E[][] = E[][]> {
    data: {
        [i in keyof T]:
        T[i] extends E[] ? {
            [j in keyof T[i]]:
            T[i][j] extends E ? E2Data[T[i][j]] : never }
        //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // Type 'T[i][j]' cannot be used to index type 'E2Data'.
        : never
    }
}
```

My current workaround is to use a type union, but this won't let me specify the data I want using a template.

```js
interface B {
    data: (E2Data[E.a] | E2Data[E.b] | E2Data[E.c])[][];
}
```

Is there a way to support the 2 methods of autocomplete on `data` as described above for a 2D array?

```js
let b1: A<[ [E.a], [E.b] ]> = {
    data: [ [{ a: "" }], [{ b: "" }] ]
}

let b2: A = {
    data: [ [<E2Data[E.a]>{ a: "" }], [ <E2Data[E.b]>{ b: "" }] ]
}
```

Comment: Do the individual arrays in B.data contain a combination of different data types, or are they grouped by type?  If you just want, for example, an array of E.a data and an array of E.b data then that is easy.  All you need to do is replace `E2Data[T[i]]` with `E2Data[T[i]][]` in interface A.  But I suspect you need to mix types or else you wouldn't have posted this.

Comment: The desired type of data was like in the workaround `interface B` . Your answer below covered that anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me some thinking, but the solution is actually pretty straightforward because you've already done most of the legwork with your original `interface A`.

Define a generic type `DataArray` which takes a tuple of E values as its generic and returns a tuple of the corresponding E2Data.  You could reformat so that `DataArray` contains the logic and `A` uses it, but for simplicity let's just access the existing logic from `A`.

```
type DataArray<T extends E[]> = A<T>['data'];
```

Instead of using a nested index signature in `interface B`, you can use a single index signature and call on the `DataArray` type to create the inner arrays.

```
interface B<T extends E[][] = E[][]> {
    data: {
        [i in keyof T]: T[i] extends E[] ? DataArray<T[i]> : never
    }
}
```

Now you create any 2D data type by mixing and matching E.

```
let b: B<[[E.a], [E.b, E.c]]> = {
    data: [ [{ a: "" }], [{ b: "" }, {c: ""}] ]
}
```

**Edit**
I know you didn't ask for this, but here's how to handle more deeply nested values.  (With some guidance from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657815/recursive-array-type-typescript) about recursive arrays).

```
interface Nested<T> extends Array<Nested<T> | T> {
}

type NestedData<T extends Nested<E>> = { 
    [i in keyof T]: T[i] extends E ? E2Data[T[i]] : T[i] extends Nested<E> ? NestedData<T[i]> : never
}

interface C<T extends Nested<E>> {
    data: NestedData<T>
}

let c: C<[E.a, [E.b, [E.c]]]> = {
    data: [ { a: "" }, [{ b: "" }, [{c: ""}] ]]
}
```