# How to combine object-or-array and recursion in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Essentially I want to achieve this:

```js
type Foo = ({bar: string} & Record<string, Foo>) | Foo[]
```

I keep running into either circular reference drawback for `type` or
`An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members` for `interface`, with something like this:

```js
type Atom = { bar: string } & Record<string, Foo>
type ArrayOrRecord = Atom | Array<Atom>
interface Foo extends ArrayOrRecord {}
```

There was a similar question raised here
[Recursive array type typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657815/recursive-array-type-typescript),
but the difference is that in my case Atom has recursive properties as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand the `Record` definition:

```
type Foo = ({bar: string} & { [K in string] : Foo }) | Foo[]
```